# potentially manifesting in discriminatory outcomes

Tags: grammar, modifiers

Just got caught out by a sentence excerpted from [an opinion](https://www.thebulwark.com/how-ai-is-being-transformed-by-foundation-models/) on the latest artificial intelligence developments:

> Others are weirded out by foundation models because any flaws or
> biases in these models risks replication in progeny systems and
> applications. **If some sort of racial bias is present in an AI
> foundation model, that bias would be embedded in other systems and
> tasks potentially manifesting in discriminatory outcomes**. Like a
> mutation in DNA, these flaws, replicated across many AI systems, could
> metastasize and become devilishly difficult to correct and eliminate.

The gist of the paragraph is crystal clear but the syntax of the sentence in bold confuses me a bit.

How does the part "potentially manifesting in discriminatory outcomes" function here? Is it a modifier that applies to "systems and tasks"? Or is it signalling things that would happen if bias is embedded in other systems and tasks?

And if the latter assumption makes more sense, then should there be a comma between "tasks" and "potentially" so as to make the structure clearer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is the embedding of the bias in systems and tasks that creates the potential for manifesting discriminatory outcomes. Systems and tasks with no embedded bias have no potential to manifest discriminatory outcomes from the bias.

From this perspective, I believe your suggestion of the comma after “tasks” makes the meaning clearer. It puts the embedding of the bias in apposition with the potential outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense as it is, though some words & Punctuation might be missing.

Here is one way to Parse it (with Punctuation & (un)necessary words only to highlight the grouping) :

> If some sort of racial bias is present in an AI foundation model, [then] ...
> ... that bias would be embedded in "other systems and tasks" [,] ...
> ... [&] [that bias would be] potentially manifesting [itself] in discriminatory outcomes

At the very least, adding a comma (after tasks) & adding "itself" (after manifesting) might help.

Alternately, we might change "manifesting in" to "manifest" , to get a slightly changed meaning :

> If some sort of racial bias is present in an AI foundation model, [then] ...
> ... that bias would be embedded in "other systems and tasks" [,] ...
> ... [which would] potentially manifest discriminatory outcomes

Answer (score 0):

*If some sort of racial bias is present in an AI foundation model, that bias would be embedded in other systems and tasks potentially manifesting in discriminatory outcomes.*
Reframe the original sentence:
If some sort of racial bias is present in an AI foundation model, that bias would be embedded in other systems and tasks, potentially manifesting discriminatory outcomes [in these].

Add a comma after tasks (as I have done above) delete 'in'; to totally clarify add "in these"
The author of the original sentence appears to have misused ellipsis.